# Swift inputAccessoryView override bug

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

I'm experiencing a weird bug with the appearance of my `inputAccessoryView`. While in the middle of a transition, it appears like so:

[image: Mid-transition]

After the transition, it appears as it should:

[image]

I override the property like so:

```
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView! {
    get {
        if composeView == nil {
            composeView = CommentComposeView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, MinimumToolbarHeight - 0.5))
            self.setupSignals()
        }

        return composeView
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone can point out any obvious flaw in what I'm doing or provide some more information on how to ensure my view appears as it should, before, during, and after transitions.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my `CommentComposeView`:

```
import UIKit

class CommentComposeView: UIToolbar {
    var textView: SAMTextView!
    var sendButton: UIButton!

    private var didSetConstraints: Bool = false

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initialize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        textView = SAMTextView(frame: CGRectZero)
        sendButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton

        self.barStyle = .Black
        self.translucent = true

        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.presentOffWhite()
        textView.font = UIFont.presentLightMedium()
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        textView.placeholder = "Comment"
        textView.scrollsToTop = false
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 3, 3, 3)
        textView.keyboardAppearance = .Dark
        textView.keyboardType = .Twitter
        self.addSubview(textView)

        sendButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
        sendButton.enabled = false
        sendButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.presentBoldLarge()
        sendButton.setTitle("Send", forState: .Normal)
        sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.presentCyan(), forState: .Highlighted)
        sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.presentLightGray(), forState: .Disabled)
        sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)
        self.addSubview(sendButton)

        RAC(self.sendButton, "enabled") <~ self.textView.rac_textSignal()
            .map { text in
                return (text as NSString).length > 0
        }

        textView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        sendButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()

        if !didSetConstraints {
            // TODO: Replace raw constraints with a friendlier looking DSL
            self.addConstraint(
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
            )

            self.addConstraint(
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 7.5)
            )

            self.addConstraint(
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: sendButton, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: -2)
            )

            self.addConstraint(
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
            )

            self.addConstraint(
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            )

            self.addConstraint(
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this issue is still up to date, please, provide complete sample. On which iOS versions do you experience this issue?

Comment: iOS 8. What else do you need? My actual `CommentComposeView`?

Answer (score 2):

This is iOS8 issue with inputAccessoryView autolayout. Issue is that UIToolbar's subview of clas `_UIToolbarBackground` is not positioned properly during initial layout. Try to do next things:

1. Make `CommentComposeView` subclassing `UIView`, not `UIToolbar`, add instance of `UIToolbar` as subview.
2. Use autolayout masks (not actual constraints) inside your `CommentComposeView`
3. Override `-layoutSubviews` in your `CommentComposeView` like this:

```c
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    contentToolbar.frame = self.bounds;
    sendButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 44.f, self.bounds.size.height);
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(44.f, 0.f, self.bounds.size.width - 44.f, self.bounds.size.height);
}
```

Comment: I did all that you suggested and I'm still experiencing the same issue. Do you have example code from your experimentation?

Comment: Sorry, my fault here, seems like there is no fix for that. When you perform slide-to-pop gesture, background of toolbar also becomes transparent. Also, there your view controller is not deallocated when you use input accessory view and pop back.

Comment: I had a similar problem (`UIToolbar` appearing black during `viewWillDisappear`) step 1 of your answer resolved this issue for me. I also set the containing `UIView`'s background color to white.

Comment: This solution worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289951/inputaccessoryviews-uitoolbar-turns-black-when-rotating-in-ios